# How to update class variable inherited from parent class

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm new to Class Object and inheritance. I was wondering how to update a class variable inherited from parent class. For example, I did this:

```
class Parent:
    type = ''
    default = 'empty'
    if type == 'A':
        default = 'This is A'
    if type == 'B':
        default = 'This is B'

    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    type = 'A'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

I want `Child.default` to be `'This is B'`, but apparently I got `Child.default` = `'empty'`.
Cound anyone point me how to achive my goal?

Comment: The body of a Python class *is evaluated as it is encountered*. So the execution occurs *before* the `class Child(Parent)` line.

Comment: A more appropriate - fsvo - approach here might be to move such logic into `__init__`, which is executed later (after the child instance is created). Then also set an *instance* member of the new object, so as to not muck with the Parent class itself (maybe B comes along later..).

Comment: Sidenote: Those `__init__()` methods are both pointless. `pass` does nothing and `super().__init__()` is implied.

Comment: Another sidenote: `type` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `type` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). You could use `type_` instead.

Comment: @user2864740 Is there a way to handle this not at the instance level but just at the class level?